# Android MySql query issue

Tags: android

I'm working on a Mysql query to search for a single row, but its throwing me some strange results, heres the simplified setup:

```
public Cursor cursor(String one, String two) throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                    KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_ONE, 
                    KEY_TWO
                    }, 
                    KEY_ONE + "=" + one + "; " + KEY_TWO + "=" + two, 
                    null,
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

Ive run this query in a loop with alternating String 2 values, the problem that occurs is that all results returned are from just one particular row from the database, even if the particular query doesn't exist with both values (I'm guessing this is a query problem?)

If I change both string 1 & 2 to something that rows on the database dont have, then the cursor returns empty.

Been following this tutorial: http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/0/page/2

Cheers in advance

Comment: fyi: Its SQLite and _not_ MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WHERE clause `KEY_ONE + "=" + one + "; " + KEY_TWO + "=" + two` is wrong

Use `KEY_ONE + "=" + one + " AND " + KEY_TWO + "=" + two` instead